# c++ class dependant typedef declared outside class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, c++98

I have two classes, which I shall call classA and classB.

In classA I have some types defined, such as T5.
In classB I use such types defined in classA.

In order to avoid writing

```
typename classA<T1,T2>::T5
```

throughout my code, I want to create a class indipendent type,
which I would be able to call directly by simply its name - templatedClassA
in the example. The template paremeters would still be parametric, and I would 
define them in future projects using classA and classB.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//classA
template <class T1, class T2>
class classA
{
 public:  
 typedef T1 T5;
 classA();
};

template <class T1, class T2>
classA<T1,T2>::classA(){}
//end classA

template <class T1, class T2>
typedef classA<T1,T2> templatedClassA;

template <class T1, class T2>
typedef typename classA<T1,T2>::T5 T6;






//classB
template <class T3, class T4>
class classB
{
 public:
 classB();
};

template <class T3, class T4>
classB<T3,T4>::classB(){}
//end classB



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    classB<int, double> classBInstance;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When compiling the above code, I get the following two errors:

```
template declaration of `typedef class classA<T1, T2> templatedClassA'
template declaration of `typedef typename classA<T1, T2>::T5 T6'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates cannot be used in `typedef` declarations. You have to wrap the declaration in a class like this:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class templatedClassA {
    typedef classA<T1, T2> type;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class T6 {
   typedef typename classA<T1, T2>::T5 type;
};
```

In C++11 you can use the `using` alias as shown in the other answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. The problem I see with templatedClassA<T1,T1>::type and T6<T1,T2>::type is that it's the same as classA<T1,T2> and class<T1,T2>::T5; It does not symplyfy notatation as I want, I makes it heavier, I think...

Comment: @geraldCelente: Is T5 only dependent on the first template argument?

Comment: Well no, in the real code no. It is dependand on a bunch of other classes and internal types.

Comment: Hm...but from what you wrote above, it seems like you are saying that templatedClassA<T1, T2>::type doesn't depend on T2. If that's the case, you could just remove the second template parameter from templatedClassA.

Comment: @geraldCelente I suppose you can use inheritance as in `template<typename T1, typename T2> struct T5 : classA<T1, T2> { };`

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you may do:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
using templatedClassA = classA<T1, T2>;

template <class T1, class T2>
using T6 = typename classA<T1, T2>::T5;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Sorry I forgot to mention that I am working on c++'98.